# How to get sum of all values in ES6 Node JS Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

My code is not able to sum of all values using Node JS. Can someone help to fix it?

Error at VS code is:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

```js
let addInput = new Map( 
  {"key1":10},
  {"key2":5},
  {"key3":7},
  {"key4":17}
);

let sum = 0;

addInput.forEach((v) => {
  sum += v;
});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: `new Map( {"key1":10}, {"key2":5}, {"key3":7}, {"key4":17} );` should throw an error and not the one you mentioned. The correction initialiser is `new Map([ ["key1", 10], ["key2", 5], ["key3", 7], ["key4", 17] ]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a `Map` of `key-value`, You can use `flatMap` here:

```
const arr = [{ key1: 10 }, { key2: 5 }, { key3: 7 }, { key4: 17 }];
let addInput = new Map(arr.flatMap((o) => Object.entries(o)));
```

```js
const arr = [{ key1: 10 }, { key2: 5 }, { key3: 7 }, { key4: 17 }];
let addInput = new Map(arr.flatMap((o) => Object.entries(o)));

let sum = 0;
addInput.forEach((v) => {
  sum += v;
});

console.log(sum);
```

I'd prefer to use `for..of` loop here

```js
const arr = [{ key1: 10 }, { key2: 5 }, { key3: 7 }, { key4: 17 }];
let addInput = new Map(arr.flatMap((o) => Object.entries(o)));

let sum = 0;
for (let [, v] of addInput) sum += v;

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: `for (const v of map.values()) { sum += v; }` also works

Answer (score -1):

You could set values for a new Map using `set` method:

```js
 let addInput = new Map();
addInput.set("key1", 10);
addInput.set("key2", 5);
addInput.set("key3", 7);
addInput.set("key4", 12);
```